# Adjust input field size to its input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a read-only field input that I would like to adjust the size of the input. I have tried through pixel size and other, but since the input field gets its input "after" with PHP, the code always recognizes the input has null/0 pixels and it doesn't adjust. I would like the solution to be html and JavaScript.

This is what I have.

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="3" align="right">Total: </td>
   <td align="right"><input id="total" readonly value="<?php echo number_format($total, 2)?>"></input>€</td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: There is no reason to have the `</input>`. Where are you setting the size?

Comment: _"the code always recognizes the input has null/0 pixels and it doesn't adjust."_ - what code? Theres only HTML here

Comment: Plain javascript?  I would tie an event handler to the window.onload method.

Comment: @epascarello I need that id to get the value later and use it in a function. I tried setting the size on the td and on the input, but I ended up going to the original line I had without the size setting

Comment: @Jamiec I tried doing it with JS but now I have nothing, I deleted it because it didn't work, hence only the HTML code. I would've posted my past tries but I don't remeber the exact code of the solutions

Comment: @GlenCarpenter how can I do that?

Comment: Ok,  well have another go and when you get stuck post the code here.